# JAVA if statement problems

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

I am using an if statement in java to determine weather the person is a male or female by asking weather he is a boy or a girl. This is quite a stupid statement but my query is no matter what i input i always get "you are a female!" which is quite annoying. Could you please help? This is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ifstatement {

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        System.out.print( "please enter boy or girl as an input:" );

        Scanner x = new Scanner( System.in );
        String a = x.nextLine();

        if ( a == "boy" ) {
            System.out.print( "You are a male" );
        }
        else {
            System.out.print( "You are a female!" );
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: When you do `a == "boy"` you are testing whether a is the *exact same instance* as the string `"boy"`, not whether or not the Strings contain the same characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to say:

```
 if ("boy".equals(a)){
 System.out.print("You are a male");
 } else if ("girl".equals(a)){
 System.out.print("you are a female!");
 { else {
 System.out.print("invalid response!");
 }
```

This would solve your problem. When dealing with strings you should always use .equals() to compare exact values. the "==" operator compares whether two objects point to the same location in memory generally. Since a string is an object they are not the same.

Comment: Thanks a ton! your answer was the most helpful

Answer (score 4):

Use `equals()` method to compare `String`

`equals()` compares the object

`==` compares the references value

Use

```
if ("boy".equals(a)) {
```

This will compare `"boy"` instance of String with String instance referred by `a`

---

**See**

- [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: and equalsIgnoreCase() if you do not care about the case.

Comment: i can't understand. will you please write that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

`==` comparison uses object reference, whether the two objects point to the same memory location. `.equals()` does the same in Object class, however, String class overrides it to do value comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal. When testing for String equality, this is not enough. A test for reference equality is done within the `String.equals() method`, among other checks:

```
 public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
        if (this == anObject) {      // Reference equality
            return true;
        }
        if (anObject instanceof String) {
            String anotherString = (String)anObject;
            int n = count;
            if (n == anotherString.count) {  // Are the strings the same size?
                char v1[] = value;
                char v2[] = anotherString.value;
                int i = offset;
                int j = anotherString.offset;
                while (n-- != 0) {
                    if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])        // Compare each character
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** In **java objects are compared using .equals() method, and Strings are objects in Java.**

**2.** Use `a.equals("boys")` and that will give you the **correct answer**....